# Link two google drive excel using google API

Tags: java, google-drive-api, spreadsheet

Hi any one have knowledge about how to link two excel on google drive using google API.
I am using java for upload file on google drive and I am linking using "import range" I am getting error for asking me allow access.
how to set permission for link two excel sheet on drive

Comment: Can you post your code and error logs?

Comment: String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
        Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(GoogleAuthUtil.getHttpTransport(), GoogleAuthUtil.getJsonFactory(), credential)
                        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());

Comment: fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                        UPLOAD_FILE); 
        File file = drive.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).execute();
        return file.getId();

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to add "within link"  permission while uploading excel file on google drive

Comment: Are the relevant permissions set on the documents at the outset? You can grant various levels of visibility from something akin to private/public/who has a link etc